# DynamoDBTypeConverted doesn't work in Java

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Logs throw

```
Converter not found for EnhancedType(java.util.ArrayList<domains.requirementsAndDefinitionForTracingEvents.Event>)
```

error.
I decided to write a custom converter

```
package converters;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter;
import domains.requirementsAndDefinitionForTracingEvents.Event;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class EventListToMapConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<List<Map<String, ?>>, List<Event>> {


    @Override
    public List<Map<String, ?>> convert(List<Event> events) {
        List<Map<String, ?>> convertedList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Event e: events) {
            Map map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("eventCode", e.getEventCode());
            map.put("remark", e.getRemark());
            map.put("requiredOwn", e.isRequiredOwn());
            convertedList.add(map);
        }
        return convertedList;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Event> unconvert(List<Map<String, ?>> stringStringMap) {
        List<Event> convertedList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Map<String, ?> map: stringStringMap) {
            Event e = new Event();
            e.setEventCode((String) map.get("eventCode"));
            e.setRemark((String) map.get("remark"));
            e.setRequiredOwn((Boolean) map.get("requiredOwn"));
            convertedList.add(e);
        }
        return convertedList;
    }
}
```

I added it like this

```
package domains.requirementsAndDefinitionForTracingEvents;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverted;
import converters.EventListToMapConverter;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbBean;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@DynamoDbBean
public class RequirementsAndDefinitionForTracingEvents {
    public RequirementsAndDefinitionForTracingEvents() {
    }

    public RequirementsAndDefinitionForTracingEvents(ArrayList<Event> tracingEventCodes, AdditionalRules additionalRules) {
        this.tracingEventCodes = tracingEventCodes;
        this.additionalRules = additionalRules;
    }
    @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = EventListToMapConverter.class)
    private ArrayList<Event> tracingEventCodes;

    private AdditionalRules additionalRules;

    public AdditionalRules getAdditionalRules() {
        return additionalRules;
    }

    public ArrayList<Event> getTracingEventCodes() {
        return tracingEventCodes;
    }

    public void setTracingEventCodes(ArrayList<Event> tracingEventCodes) {
        this.tracingEventCodes = tracingEventCodes;
    }

    public void setAdditionalRules(AdditionalRules additionalRules) {
        this.additionalRules = additionalRules;
    }
}
```

but actually nothing changed. Still the same error. What's the problem in here?
I heard of another thing which are converted properties in
@DynamoDBBean attribute but it is quite hard to understand for me if I want to map List<Map<String, ?>>

Also I have seen that @DynamoDBConvertedType is usually used with @DynamoDBDocument but couldn't find any proper for me documentation. I have template.yaml file where I define table name which can be 'TABLE_NAME'. Then do I define @DynamoDBTable attribute on the main object with TableName = 'TABLE_NAME' ?
Should I mark every child class as @DynamoDBDocument? Will it work or it doesn't matter if I use dynamodbbean or dynamodbdocument if I still parse my JSON file with a gson parser?

Answer (score 0):

Well, just needed to change ArrayList to List :- )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).